# Div Width not changing

Tags: html, width

```
    overflow:auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top:20px;
    min-height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #E8E8E8;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #999;
```

I may not have provided the sufficient information to help anyone answer my question and so if there is any need for more info, please tell me.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div width is probably not changing because you don't seem to have a width property:value assigned to it. You need to include width:200px or width:100% or something along those lines.

Comment: Furthermore, it's apparent that your probably new to php, html. So just for clarification its called a html div. You might be using php to add the div but it still boils down to html.

Comment: I am sorry about that. I had asked this question somewhere else to and for troubleshooting, they asked me to take out the width to see if anything changes when the width is not present. It didn't affect the website and the problem was still there. I forgot to copy back the width when I pasted the code here. The width is supposed to be width:800px. I tried changing it to 300px or 500px but nothing changed.

Comment: There might be a conflicting width somewhere in your css. My advice would be to get fimilar with google developer tools [http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/] to trouble shoot your css. Without a link its hard to see exactly what the problem is.